# How can I recursively split a population?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to split a population of Xs (continuous) and Ys (binary) equally (by count) until a "breakpoint" is found. For example, the below code should generate 5,000 observations with each half having a different proportion of 0s and 1s. I want to then split the half with the larger proportion of 1s and so on and so forth until there is no way to split anymore.

EDIT: My data is not normally distributed but I had to generate fake data for this example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(191)
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randint( 0,2,size = ( 5000,1 ) ), columns = list( 'Y' ) )
df['X'] = pd.Series( random.choices( range( 5000 ), k = 5000) )

# Creating equal-sized bins
df['bins'] = pd.qcut( df['X'], 2 )
print( df.groupby('bins')['Y'].value_counts() )
print( df.groupby('bins')['Y'].mean() )

# Next I want to take the bins with the larger proportion of 1s and repeat the qcut until a minimum/maximum(?) is reached
```

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're trying to do. Maybe you could clarifiy a few points: Do you want to split your data *exactly* in half? (i.e. 2500 observations in each bin).
So thereafter you want to take the 2500 with the highest proportion of 1s and continue? Then take 1250, etc.? What does "there is no way to split anymore" mean to you? That the bottom and top half both have the same number of 1s? What is the expected output of your function supposed to be? What have you tried so far and where exactly are you getting stuck? Is it that you need help writing a recursive function?

Comment: @Karl, to answer your questions: Yes, I want to split the population exactly in half and then take the half with the higher proportion of 1s and continue. You're also correct about the end condition, both proportions are the same and no decision can be made. I'm expecting to find a point along the continuous variable where the values greater than that point have a higher proportion (density) of 1s than those lower than that point. For example, after all the splits the "breakpoint" is found to be 200. A new observation with a continuous variable of 200 or less is likely to be a 0.

Comment: Ok, still not very clear to me sorry. Let's say we have data [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]. After the first iteration this becomes [5,6,7,8] and [1,1,1,0]. After another iteration it becomes [5,6] and [1,1] at which point you can no longer split. What does that tell us?

Comment: That tells us that a new observation (say, another 6) is more likely to be a 1 than a 0. The [5,6] couldn't be split so the original split [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8] is the best "breakpoint'. That is, new observations are treated as "less than or equal to 4" or "greater than 4". A new dummy variable if you will.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

SIZE = 5000

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(SIZE, 1)), columns=list('Y'))
df['X'] = pd.Series(random.choices(range(5000), k=SIZE))


def splitting(df):

    # base case - no way to split anymore - only 0s or only 1s are in 'Y'
    if df['Y'].unique().shape[0] == 1:
        return df
    # recursion
    else:
        df['bins'] = pd.qcut(df['X'], 2)
        label = df.groupby('bins')['Y'].mean().idxmax()
        df_1 = df[df['bins'] != label].copy()
        df_2 = df[df['bins'] == label].copy()
        return pd.concat([df_1, splitting(df_2)])


result = splitting(df)
```